# How to determine if the given object is of given type in Python?

Tags: python, types

I always thought operator `is` determined if the given variable is of the given type. But I just determined it was not true:

```
>>> class A():
      pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a is A
False
```

How do I test if `a` is of type `class A`?

Please advise.

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: it seems like with every newbie a wave of duplicates overwhelms SO. you just have to look to your right if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `isinstance(a, A)`.

Keep in mind, it might be better to avoid the `isinstance` check by adding methods to `A` that make it do what you want without explicitly determining that it is an `A`.

`is` determines if two objects are the same object.

Comment: Adding to what Ned correctly mentioned, `a is b` is the same as doing `id(a) == id(b)`

Answer (score 2):

[isinstance(a,A)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)